# loss of data in crypt function in C

Tags: c, crypt

Based on the crypt.c example I have the following code, but when I run it password1 gets corrupted during the second call to crypt. Can anyone spot the problem?

Entering the same password to both requests should result in the same value for all three strings at the end.

================================================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

/*
cc calc1.c -ocalc1 -lcrypt
*/

int main(void) {
    unsigned long seed[2];
    char salt[] = "$1$zhodFRlE$";
    char *password2,*password1,*temp1;
    int i,ok;
    printf("%s is Salt\n",salt);

    password1 = crypt(getpass("Password1 :"), salt);

    printf("Crypt Password1: %s\n",password1);
    temp1 = strdup(password1);
    printf("Crypt temp1: %s\n",temp1);

    password2 = crypt(getpass("Password2 :"),temp1);

    printf("Crypt Password1: %s\n",password1);
    printf("Crypt temp1: %s\n",temp1);
    printf("Crypt Password2: %s\n",password2);
    return 0;
}
```

================================================================

Comment: What is `crypt()` definition when does it returns NULL **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - [crypt() man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt)

Comment: Ahaa ..Standard function Thanks @Mike!

Comment: Used pw "1234" on both prompts, came up with "Crypt Password1: $1CH2LCw5hraY", "Crypt temp1: $1CH2LCw5hraY", "Crypt Password2: $1CH2LCw5hraY".  All 3 the same.  Cygwin gcc version 4.5.3.  Hope this helps.  Maybe library(s) needs re-build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that this function:

```
char *crypt(const char *key, const char *salt);
```

returns a temporary pointer that will be overwritten the next time you call that function.  What you want to do in order to not overwrite the previously returned data:

```
char *crypt_r(const char *key, const char *salt,
                 struct crypt_data *data);
```

instead; this allows you to pass in a structure that includes a buffer to keep the encrypted password.  See the man page for crypt for more information.

That will take care of your disappearing password1.

Separately, this is not true:  "Entering the same password to both requests should result in the same value for all three strings at the end."  By using a different salt, you'll get a different encrypted value.

Comment: Is that why my 'temp1' which is an strdup keeps its data intact?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes.  The strdup copies password1 to temp1 *before* it password1 overwritten by the second `crypt` call.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a different salt value into the second call to crypt() - this will result in different return values even if the passwords are the same.

Comment: Not really - you'll notice the salt appears at the beginning of the encrypted password - delimited by $ as per spec.

Comment: The problem is not different values but complete loss of value in password1 - I've been looking for memory leaks but to no avail.